# Is it possible to define a custom image suffix for iPhone 6 Plus, while still using the same points sizes as on iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, iphone-6-plus

We have an app that is made for iPhone 4/5 and iPad/iPad Retina. The interface XIB files for iPhone do not use dynamic layout, and the code that places UI elements assumes a screen width of 320 points and a screen height of 480 or 568 (iPhone 5) points.

Due to a lack of time, we currently can't adapt the app for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus the "right way" (by changing the XIB files to use dynamic layout, and changing the code to work with variable screen widths/heights, then testing all the UI positioning again). But we easily can generate higher-resolution versions of the images.

I've experimented with the following: I *don't* add a Launch Image for iPhone 6 / 6 Plus; as a result, the app simply runs upscaled on an iPhone 6 Plus, and the screen still has 320 x 568 points. Everything runs fine, but the graphics are very blurry.

However, if I load a higher-resolution image (e.g. 1242 x 2208 pixels for the background) and set an UI element to use this image, then the image is sharp. (I'm testing with the simulator; don't have an iPhone 6 Plus available; I hope the behaviour is the same on a device).

Instead of adding the above workaround for each image individually, what I want to do is: at the start of the app, check the model of the device, and in case of iPhone 6 Plus, tell the app to use a custom image suffix. This suffix should be used for all images, not only those that are loaded via code, but also the images that are specified in XIB files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't complicate yourself. just like retina with suffix @2x, you have to add @3x for iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: No, as long as I don't implement a launch image, iOS doesn't consider the app to be adjusted for iPhone 6 Plus, and doesn't try to use images with the "3x" suffix.

Comment: Oh dear, you were actually right from the start: even if I don't supply an iPhone 6/6Plus Launch Image, the app does use "@3x" images on iPhone 6 Plus.
I have tried "@3x" images before and couldn't get them to work. Now that I tried again, it worked. Must have made some error before.
I marked your answer as correct, thank you.